# OpenGL + Cloth simulation physics isn't working

Tags: c++, opengl

I am attempting to implement a cloth simulation using a spring-particle system but something isn't quite right with my physics. When I run the simulation the cloth draws as expected but over time the force of gravity pulls the cloth downward indefinitely. In other words the forces caused by the springs are not accumulating properly to overcome the downward pull of gravity and I end up with this...:
[image]

It continues to droop downwards indefinitely. From all of the debugging I have done what I have seen is that the accumulation of forces on a particle caused by all of the springs attached to it is not properly summing when the force of gravity causes increased stretch. I can not figure out what I have overlooked in my physics.

My cloth updates every time step using this function

```
void Cloth::updateGeometry(atlas::utils::Time const& t) {
    for (int i = 0; i < mSprings.size(); ++i) {
        mSprings[i].calculateForces();
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < mParticles.size(); ++i) {
        mParticles[i].updateGeometry(t);
    }
}
```

My springs update using the below function where p1 and p2 are pointers to each particle that this spring is attached to.

```
void Spring::calculateForces() {
    glm::vec3 springVector = normalize((p2->getCurrentPosition() - p1->getCurrentPosition()));
    GLfloat stretchLength = length(p2->getCurrentPosition(),  p1->getCurrentPosition());
    GLfloat displacementFromRest = restLength - stretchLength;
    glm::vec3 springForce = -k * displacementFromRest * normalize(springVector);
    //Multiply the displacements by the spring constant to get 
    //A vector which represents the force on each spring
    p1->addToSumOfSpringForces(springForce);
    p2->addToSumOfSpringForces(-springForce);
}
```

Finally my particles update using.

```
void Particle::updateGeometry(atlas::utils::Time const& t) {
    if (!stationary) {
        previousPosition = currentPosition;
        glm::vec3 forceOfGravity = mass * gravity;
        glm::vec3 totalForce = forceOfGravity + (mass * totalSpringForces) - velocity*Damping;
        acceleration = totalForce / mass;

        //Perform Euler Integration
        currentPosition += t.deltaTime * velocity;
        velocity += t.deltaTime * acceleration;

        //============== End Euler==============//

        //Reset the forces acting on the particle from all of the springs
        //So that a new accumulated total can be calculated.
        totalSpringForces = glm::vec3{ 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f };    
    }
}
```

The `totalSpringForces` variable is updated by the call to `addToSumOfSpringForces(springForce);` in the spring update function. The idea is that each spring is evaluated first according to the current position of each particle then each particle's `totalSpringForce`variable is accumulated each iteration using

```
void Particle::addToSumOfSpringForces(glm::vec3 force) {
    totalSpringForces += force;
}
```

Just to add clarification the cloth is constructed using structural, bend and shear springs in accordance with [this](https://sites.google.com/site/ofauckland/examples/17-cloth-physics) description. This may be unneccesary but I've included my cloth constructor below.

```
Cloth::Cloth(GLfloat width_, GLfloat height_, GLuint numParticlesWide_, GLuint numParticlesHigh_) :
    width(width_),
    height(height_),
    numParticlesHigh(numParticlesHigh_),
    numParticlesWide(numParticlesWide_),
    clothRotationVector{0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f},
    clothPosition{ 0.0f, 5.0f, 0.0f },
    clothRotationAngle(0.0f)
{
    USING_ATLAS_MATH_NS;
    USING_ATLAS_GL_NS;
    glm::vec3 clothColour{1.0f, 0.5f, 0.2f};
    //Create Particles
    GLuint count = 0;
    restLength = (width * (1 / (float)numParticlesWide));
    for (GLuint y = 0; y < numParticlesHigh; ++y) {
        for (GLuint x = 0; x < numParticlesWide; ++x) {
            glm::vec3 pos = {(width * (x / (float)numParticlesWide)), (-height * (y / (float)numParticlesHigh)), 0.0f};
            mParticles.push_back(Particle(pos, count, clothColour));
            ++count;
        }
    }
    //Create Springs
    for (GLuint x = 0; x < numParticlesWide; ++x) {
        for (GLuint y = 0; y < numParticlesHigh; ++y) {

            //============ Structural springs ==========//
            //Connect to the particle to the immediate right of the current particle
            if (x < numParticlesWide - 1) mSprings.push_back(Spring(getParticle(x,y), getParticle(x+1,y)));

            //Connect to the particle that is immediately below the current particle
            if (y < numParticlesHigh - 1) mSprings.push_back(Spring(getParticle(x,y), getParticle(x,y+1)));

            //============ Shear Springs ================//
            //Connect the shear springs to make the X pattern
            if (x < numParticlesWide - 1 && y < numParticlesHigh - 1) {
                mSprings.push_back(Spring(getParticle(x, y), getParticle(x + 1, y + 1)));
                mSprings.push_back(Spring(getParticle(x+1, y), getParticle(x, y+1)));
            }

            //============ Bend Springs ===============//
            //Connect the current particle to the second particle over to the right
            if (x < numParticlesWide - 2) mSprings.push_back(Spring(getParticle(x,y), getParticle(x+2,y)));

            //Connect the current particle to the particle two below
            if (y < numParticlesHigh - 2) mSprings.push_back(Spring(getParticle(x,y), getParticle(x, y+2)));

            ////Create the X pattern 
            //if (x < numParticlesWide - 2 && y < numParticlesHigh - 2) {
            //  mSprings.push_back(Spring(getParticle(x, y), getParticle(x+2,y+2)));
            //  mSprings.push_back(Spring(getParticle(x+2,y), getParticle(x,y+2)));
            //};
        }
    }

    //Set the top left and right as stationary
    getParticle(0, 0)->makeStationary();
    getParticle(numParticlesWide - 1, 0)->makeStationary();

    //Make Indices for Particles
    for (GLuint row = 0; row < numParticlesWide - 1; ++row) {
        for (GLuint col = 0; col < numParticlesHigh - 1; ++col) {
            //Triangle one
            mParticleIndices.push_back(getParticle(row,col)->getIndex());
            mParticleIndices.push_back(getParticle(row,col+1)->getIndex());
            mParticleIndices.push_back(getParticle(row+1, col)->getIndex());

            //Triangle two
            mParticleIndices.push_back(getParticle(row, col+1)->getIndex());
            mParticleIndices.push_back(getParticle(row+1, col+1)->getIndex());
            mParticleIndices.push_back(getParticle(row+1, col)->getIndex());
        }
    }
    glGenBuffers(1, &clothVertexBufferID);
    glGenBuffers(1, &clothIndexBufferID);
    sendDataToGPU();
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, clothIndexBufferID);
    glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, mParticleIndices.size() * sizeof(GLushort), &mParticleIndices[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    defineVAO();

    std::string shaderDir = generated::ShaderPaths::getShaderDirectory();
    std::vector<ShaderInfo> shaders
    {
        { GL_VERTEX_SHADER, shaderDir + "Cloth.vs.glsl" },
        { GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER, shaderDir + "Cloth.fs.glsl" }
    };
    mModel = glm::translate(Matrix4(1.0f), clothPosition);
    mShaders.push_back(ShaderPointer(new Shader));
    mShaders[0]->compileShaders(shaders);
    mShaders[0]->linkShaders();
    mUniforms.insert(UniformKey("mvpMat",mShaders[0]->getUniformVariable("mvpMat")));
    mShaders[0]->disableShaders();
}
```

*EDIT*

I have verified that the `totalSpringForces`variable is indeed changing. I added a print statement in my Particle update function which you can see in the image below. The selected the `totalSpringForces` for only particle #55 which in this case is the particle immediately under particle 0 which is stationary and not allowed to move. Also the printout is after about 20-25 iterations. As you can see the `totalSpringForces`in the y direction has positive value of 0.7037 (i.e. is counteracting gravity). I let it run for half an hour and it only got to 5.

Currently my constants are

```
k = 2.0f
mass = 0.1f
damping = 0.55f
gravity{ 0.0f, -9.81f, 0.0f },
```

[image]

Comment: I couldn't spot any obvious mistakes. Could you verify if your `springForce` is actually changing over time? Oh and from a physics point of view: dont multiply springForce with the mass when adding to totalForce, but that shouldn`t cause this effect.

Comment: Try increasing k, and try calling void Cloth::updateGeometry(atlas::utils::Time const& t) twice per update. I think you have the physics right, but it just needs some adjustment.

Comment: Might try [Verlet instead](https://web.archive.org/web/20090207201346/http://teknikus.dk/tj/gdc2001.htm).  The constraints seem easier to implement.